# How should I model a database with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm just starting to use Entity Framework Designer. I would like to ask how should I create my Entity files. I would like to have like 10 tables and all of them will be linked to at least one other table by some row. Should I create just one file and put all my models there or create a separate file for each model.

I don't know if this is even a question but I could find my answer on Google. I didn't know how to define it actually... :D

So if you have any tips on how I should model my database that will be awesome. Also if you have any more information on when I should use different Entity files that will be useful too.

I have used MySQL designer in the past but in there as far as i can remember you just move the model into the designer and you can make relations. So I'm kinda keen into doing that (all models in one Entity File) but wanted to check with you first guys.

Answer (score 0):

just try this plugin for VS http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d to generate your classes from existing db

Comment: I don't have an existing one. I can model it but my question is still what is the best practice? One Entity file with all models or a single model in a single Entity file. It's more of a theoretical question...